# Communication between a stationary observer and a spaceship traveling at near lightspeed

Tags: science-based, physics, space-travel

I was wondering about the possibilities of communication between a stationary observer and a spaceship traveling at near light-speed(lets say 99.99%). If the observer can send out signals at a certain interval for the whole duration of the journey directed at the position of the spaceship, when would each signal reach the spaceship.

Also, If the journey was for 10 years 500 years would have passed for the observer according to the formula for time dilation. If the observer was sending messages to the planet each year for this time, when the spaceship reaches its destination, would it receive all 500 messages at the same time or would they be staggered.

Comment: Is the observer in front of, beside, or behind the space-ship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bob and Alice start in the same place with synchronized clocks. Alice is flying away from Bob towards Planet X at $v=.9998c$. Assign Alice time $\tau$, assign Bob time $t$. Bob sends a message to Alice every $\Delta t$. Approximate $\gamma(.9998c) = 50$.

In Bob's frame, Alice gets the $n$'th message at $t_n = \dfrac{vn \Delta t}{c-v}$. No relativity required yet, since we haven't switched frames. So far this is exactly the same question as "Alice and Signal are in a foot race. Alice starts first traveling at $v_1$. Signal starts after $\Delta t$, traveling at $v_2 \gt v_1$. When does Signal catch Alice?"

Since Planet X is only 500LY away in Bob's Frame and Alice has a 1 LY (Bob) head start, and Bob sent his first message after 1 year (Bob), Alice is almost a light year past Planet X by the time Bob's first message reaches it. Alice gets Bob's first message 5000 years after Alice left.

If Alice slams on the brakes right as she gets to Planet X, boosting back into Bob's frame (and magically doesn't vaporize herself and her space ship by doing so), Bob's first message will reach her a little less than a year after she enters orbit, and then she'll get one message a year after that for the next 500 years.

---

An earlier edit of this answer mentioned a relativity of simultaneity issue, but there is no such issue. The only reason the math checked out  was because I had used a poor approximation of the Lorentz factor, since corrected.

---

Note in Alice's frame the distance is 10LY, not 500LY, Alice is stationary, and Bob and Planet X are moving at $-v$ with time dilation factor $\gamma=50$. When Bob sends the message after 1 year in Bob's time, that's 50 years in Alice's time. The message travels to Alice at $c$, which takes another 50 years, so Alice gets the first message 100 years after Bob left (and 90 years after planet X zips past at $.9998 c$). Alice and Bob agree that Alice's clock reads $100 yr$, they just disagree about the reason: Bob measures Alice 5000 years later with a time dilation factor of 50 making her clock read 100 years; Alice measures Alice 100 years later while a 50x shorter cosmos zips past at close to the speed of light.

Answer (score 5):

They can send signal and they will not receive them at the same time. Light speed is always *c* no matter the relative motion.

What they will observe is [relativistic Doppler effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect):

> The relativistic Doppler effect is the change in frequency, wavelength and amplitude of light, caused by the relative motion of the source and the observer (as in the classical Doppler effect), when taking into account effects described by the special theory of relativity.
>
> The relativistic Doppler effect is different from the non-relativistic Doppler effect as the equations include the time dilation effect of special relativity and do not involve the medium of propagation as a reference point. They describe the total difference in observed frequencies and possess the required Lorentz symmetry.
>
> Astronomers know of three sources of redshift/blueshift: Doppler shifts; gravitational redshifts (due to light exiting a gravitational field); and cosmological expansion (where space itself stretches). This article concerns itself only with Doppler shifts.

> [image]
>
> In figure a comparison of the relativistic Doppler effect (top) with the non-relativistic effect (bottom)

Observe how the effect strongly depends on the position of the observer relative to the motion direction.